# Objective-c to Swift conversion

Tags: objective-c, swift

```
- (NSData *)formEncodedParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
{
    NSArray *pairs = [parameters.allKeys mappedArrayWithBlock:^id(id obj) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",
            [obj stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
            [parameters[obj] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }];

    NSString *formBody = [pairs componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];

 return [formBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

> What is the best way to convert this method to Swift?

Comment: have you tried it yet?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's simply about translating code from one language to another. StackOverflow is not a code translation service.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist there is nothing wrong with questions about objc to swift conversion as long as the OP shows some efforts and pinpoint what exactly he cannot achieve. Swift is now a focal point for OSX/iOS developers and conversion from objc is not always trivial so do expect to see a lot of these here:)

Comment: @giorashc Yes, it is possible to ask a good and relevant language translation question, but this is not it. As _this_ question is currently phrased. I consider it off-topic.

Comment: @giorashc and "as long as the OP shows some efforts and pinpoint what exactly he cannot achieve" is what this question is missing.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist with that I have no argument;)

Answer (score 2):

Below is a link to a Objective-C to Swift code "converter". It probably matches syntax and replaces it with what it thinks will be appropriate.... but still.... you really have to do this kind of thing yourself. Learn how to code in Swift and then convert it yourself.

In the mean time (for educational reasons) you can try this converter: http://objectivec2swift.net/#/about

Comment: Did you want to add a hyperlink to the word "Here"? Otherwise I can't see which *Here* you have in mind.